# How to get node id on hook_page_build(&$page)

Tags: nodes, hooks, uri

I wrote a hook like so:

```
function john_page_build(&$page)
{
  $akeys = array_keys($page['content']['system_main']['nodes']);
  print $akeys[0];
}
```

On pages with urls like `http://mysite.com/page/43`, it will print the node id for that page.  However, on a page with url like `http://mysite.co/page/43/done?sid=2`, drupal gives a warning saying that `$page['content']['system_main']['nodes']` does not exist.

Is there a consistent way to get the node id WITHOUT parsing the url?

Answer (score 6):

Still comes through the URL indirectly, but this is the easiest way to get it: [menu_get_object](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7).

```
<?
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
 $nid = $node->nid;
}
?>
```

Note that if there is a node, it was already loaded by the menu system anyway and this is loaded from the static cache.

Refer [this discussion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38779/get-nodeid-in-drupal/38780#38780) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Never use arg() in d7 (by [chx](http://drupal.org/user/9446))! To get actual node, use [`menu_get_object()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7), on node pages this will return the complete $node object.

Comment: Why not use arg() in D7? Do you have a link you can share? Thx.

Comment: Avoid use of this function where possible, as resulting code is hard to read. In menu callback functions, attempt to use named arguments. See the explanation in menu.inc for how to construct callbacks that take arguments. When attempting to use this function to load an element from the current path, e.g. loading the node on a node page, use menu_get_object() instead. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7

Answer (score 0):

To get nid in your hook from url, you can use arg() function as below

```
function john_page_build(&$page)
{
  $nid = arg(1);
  echo $nid;
}
```

Comment: what if i have seo friendly urls and the node id does not appear in the address?  Will arg(1) still give me the node id?

Comment: yes you will get

Comment: I just tried it.  Going to the url /john/home/welcome, the echo arg(1) printed the word 'home' to the browser instead of the node id of 78

Comment: i am able to get node id even though URL alias used, is /john/home/welcome a url alias for a node?