# Insert a node field programmatically

Tags: theming

I have a `<div>` containing a node (a Basic Page), which has a title, body and a header image. I do not want to display the header image inside that div, so I removed it from the block layout. I would like the header image to be in the html before the `<div>`, that is, outside of the div into which the given content type is outputted (so I cannot solve this via block layout, since the image field is to be outputted outside of the content block).

Can I somehow programmatically instruct my theme to display the header image of my Basic Page? Or is there a better way how to do it?

Example: 
I need to change this:

```
<div>
<img src="headerimage.jpg">
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>body</b>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<img src="headerimage.jpg">
<div>
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>body</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Which Drupal version?

Answer (score 0):

You can put php code in a block template and write something like:

```
$node = node_load($node_id);
```

and then access the specific field you want to show like:

```
print $node->title;
print $node->field_yourfield["und"][0]["value"]
```

Edit:

Also, you can modify the node template for the teaser, copying the node.tpl.php file in your subtheme (you can look how to make a subtheme [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125)) and putting the html structure you want inside:

```
if($teaser)
{
...
}
```

There are other displays available for nodes other than page and teaser.

Comment: sorry for the basic question... but how do I get the node ID?

Comment: hmmm. Ok, first question is: Are you loading onlyu one node or is this applied to multiple nodes? If you're only loading a node and you know which is it, the node id is the number that appears in the url (like yourpage.com/node/143 ). If you're applying it to multiple nodes, it depopends on how you're getting them.

Comment: I'm applying this to multiple nodes. These are normal Basic Pages, I didn't add programming to the way they are aquired, so I assume the standard Drupal logic for displaying content is used. I only changed page.html.twig, which only contains {{ content }} in  a div, said simply.

Comment: You can check the node.tpl.php file as  suggested.

Comment: @Ondrej **For Drupal 7 [How to get nodeid?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38779/how-to-get-nodeid)** For Drupal 8 [How to get current node id in Drupal 8?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145823/how-to-get-current-node-id-in-drupal-8)